# Actionscript adding an element to object in arraycollection

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, arraycollection

How can I add an element to object in arraycollection?

Example code:

```
var mycollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
var myobject:Object=new Object();
myobject["label"]="My Label";
myobject["data"]="My data";
mycollection.addItem(myobject);
```

If later on, I want to add extra element, let say "date" to myobject in mycollection, how can I do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is with Flex more than Flash...

If you still have the reference to myobject, it is as simple as:

```
myobject["date"]= new Date();
```

If you want to trigger viewers of the collection to update their views of the collection, you would also likely have to do:

```
mycollection.itemUpdated(myobject, "date", null, myobject["date"]);
```

Cheers,
Terry